A range where value is in the right of text randomly. I want to sum all the values by finding the text across all columns and rows
Need total value of a, b & c
I've tried with offset function with match & column nested. It worked but only for first matching value from a column.
Example: =IFNA(OFFSET($B$3,MATCH($L3,B$3:B$19,0)-1,COLUMNS($B$1:B1),1,1),0)+IFNA(OFFSET($B$3,MATCH($L3,C$3:C$19,0)-1,COLUMNS($B$1:C1),1,1),0)+IFNA(OFFSET($B$3,MATCH($L3,D$3:D$19,0)-1,COLUMNS($B$1:D1),1,1),0)+IFNA(OFFSET($B$3,MATCH($L3,E$3:E$19,0)-1,COLUMNS($B$1:E1),1,1),0)+IFNA(OFFSET($B$3,MATCH($L3,F$3:F$19,0)-1,COLUMNS($B$1:F1),1,1),0)+IFNA(OFFSET($B$3,MATCH($L3,G$3:G$19,0)-1,COLUMNS($B$1:G1),1,1),0)+IFNA(OFFSET($B$3,MATCH($L3,H$3:H$19,0)-1,COLUMNS($B$1:H1),1,1),0)+IFNA(OFFSET($B$3,MATCH($L3,I$3:I$19,0)-1,COLUMNS($B$1:I1),1,1),0). [It sums the value of a].
I've same text more than 1 time in a single column. Also text in value column actually.

Please share a data, but not as image.

Try the following formula in L3 and drag it down:
=SUM(IF(B$3:H$19=L3,C$3:I$19)) 


Thanks @Z. Absolutely working this but need Ctrl+Shift Enter for being array formula. Thanks again.

=SUMIF(B$3:H$19,L3,C$3:I$19)
